# C++ How To Parse User's Input as Code to Execute?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, parsing

**Important Note: I'm not allowed to use external code or libraries but my own written code in C++11**

I'm looking to implement a graph calculator that will take user input as string and convert it to real code (execute it). Until now I've finished implementing all functions like operator+, operator- etc... and I'm stuck on parsing user input.

**For example,** I want to allow the following commands which **are legit**:

```
G1= {a,b | <a,b>}
G2    = {   c,d | <c,   d>}
print(G1)
print( G1+G2)
G1+G2+G3//will be interpreted as (G1+G2)+G3
G1+(G2+G3)
```

While the following aren't:

```
print( G 1)
print (G2)()
pri nt (G1)
G1 + G 3
```

But how may I do that? (I'm looking for ideas, algorithms not code)

First, I thought about reading input and removing extra spaces from it but an input like `pri nt (G1)` which isn't legit will be legit.

Second, I considered saving all legit commands in a table like `XprintX(XLegalExpressionGoesHereX)X` and allowing spaces in every place where `X` appears but I got stuck too into something that seems to be impossible

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement a tokenizer / lexer / parser (look up those terms). Maybe also look up "Bison"..

Comment: Please take a look at Flex/Bison API for C++, which allows you to do such things.

Comment: I recommend reading a book about parsers. And another about interpreters.

Comment: [Boost Spirit Qi](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) might be useful too.

Comment: Writing a language interpreter is *not* a simple task. Do you know what an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) is? If not, research that as well.

Comment: @Galaxy I can't use external code only my own written code using templates, stl, built in libraries and so on (it's a project and we allowed to get external help since we know nothing about parsing and have 4 days to finish this one)

Comment: My recommendation would be to include a Javascript, Python or Lua interpreter rather than writing your own syntax/language

Comment: @Lalaland not allowed, only C++ :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### C++ How To Parse User's Input as Code to Execute?

If you are writing your own lexer/parser from scratch using C/C++, I recommend looking at this tutorial, what approach they use.
Have a look at the first two chapters.

https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html

This YouTube playlist is a series of videos about a lecturer going over the code in the article and writing it in real time. If you rather prefer to watch someone having a lecture, instead of just reading an article with some code.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSq9OFrD2Q3ChEc_ejnBcO5u9JeT0ufkg

---

Compiler Design in C is also a good book if you can understand it. There are a lot of details, but it maybe advanced topics.

https://holub.com/goodies/compiler/compilerDesignInC.pdf

Comment: At first, I had no idea what the OP meant.  You're correct: he apparently wants to a) parse some "commands", then b) "execute" them, c) doing both the "parsing" and "execution" in C++.  Your link: [C++ How To Parse User's Input as Code to Execute?](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/) is an excellent suggestion!

Comment: Don't forget the infamous [Dragon Book](https://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Alfred-Aho/dp/0201100886/ref=pd_lpo_14_img_1/131-3654793-9669061?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0201100886&pd_rd_r=77eeb16b-605c-4aae-9a0c-9229030b0948&pd_rd_w=FoEWL&pd_rd_wg=YuJ1v&pf_rd_p=7b36d496-f366-4631-94d3-61b87b52511b&pf_rd_r=0MZRXY9PWWXTAA7WY0KN&psc=1&refRID=0MZRXY9PWWXTAA7WY0KN)

Comment: This YouTube playlist is a series of videos about a lecturer going over the code in the article and writing it in real time.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSq9OFrD2Q3ChEc_ejnBcO5u9JeT0ufkg

Comment: Here is also a PDF version of the **Dragon book**.
http://ce.sharif.edu/courses/94-95/1/ce414-2/resources/root/Text%20Books/Compiler%20Design/Alfred%20V.%20Aho,%20Monica%20S.%20Lam,%20Ravi%20Sethi,%20Jeffrey%20D.%20Ullman-Compilers%20-%20Principles,%20Techniques,%20and%20Tools-Pearson_Addison%20Wesley%20(2006).pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are implement the calculator, first you've to define the `Context Free Grammar(CFG)` for that calculator language. The steps needs to be taken to declare `CFG` are:

1. define terminals
2. define non-terminals
3. define production rules

For know more about `CFG`, you may read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) or you may check some books on `Theory of computing`. Then, you can read some books on `compiler/language design`. But I think, knowing `CFG` is enough to design your own simple language.

Comment: all of this in 4 days?

Comment: what do you mean by 4 days?

Comment: With a calculator, there is more involved than parsing.  There is also precedence, for example, multiplication and division have higher precedence than division.  Search the internet for "c++ shunting yard algorithm".

Comment: yes, there's a lot of things involved, but first one has to build parse tree, then one may apply op precedence, left recursion, left factoring whatever necessary for their language...